# How to differentiate between a month, and the first day of a month in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In moment I am parsing dates from CSV, with the option to add formatting.

Sometimes the dates are dates and will be handled as points in time. Sometimes the dates are fragments, describing a year, a month and so on. This will be handled as a range.

See the following code:

```
var a = moment('Jun 2014');
var b = moment('01-06-2014');

//output
a.toDate(); // Sun Jun 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
b.toDate(); // Sun Jun 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

I understand that a missing day will be interpreted as day 0 (or 1) but is there any way for me to differentiate between the date 1st June and the month June when parsing dates?

Comment: A `Date` in JavaScript is always a timestamp including year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds and milliseconds. So, no, moment will always convert it into a timestamp - or `moment`.

Comment: That is a valid point, I should find a different way of describing a month than to force it to be a date object. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be easiest to wrap your date parsing in another function that attaches metadata to the result. Here's a rough idea:

```
function parseDate(d) {
  var ret = moment(d);

  if(d.indexOf('-') === -1) {
    ret.monthOnly = true;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: This would work, given that all dates conforming to some string patterns. Unfortunately I receive data in a lot of funky formats ( 'Jun 2014', '31 08 2014',  '01/06/2014', '2014', '6-7-14'). All dates are valid, but no obvious pattern emerges.

Comment: Yeah. It gets kind of tough then. Can you tell different conventions (day, month, year - month, day, year etc.) apart? That could be another problem for you.

Comment: Based on your input, I'll add an option on parsing to restrict dates by year, month or week, it will then create start and end dates for all dates falling between these. I'll accept your answer as the best bet :-)